# Comparar valores de 2 arrays com PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Caros colegas,

Tenho a seguinte situação:

BD 01

```
ID | DESCRICAO | DRADS
1  | REGISTRO1 | 1,2,3
2  | REGISTRO2 | 1
```

BD 02

```
ID | DESCRICAO | DRADS
1  | REGISTRO1 | 1,2
2  | REGISTRO2 | 1
```

E preciso fazer um `<select></select>` puxando somente os registros do BD 01 que tenham as mesmas DRADS do BD 02... Ou seja, o BD 01 somente vai conseguir selecionar o(s) registro(s) que estiver(em) com a(s) mesma(s) DRADS do BD 02.

Os valores do BD 01, eu obtenho através de um `while(...)`. Já os valores do BD 02, eu obtenho através de `$_SESSION['BD_02_DRADS']`.

Já tentei comparar os valores de `$_SESSION['BD_02_DRADS'] + $row['BD_01_DRADS']` com as funções `in_array()` e `array_diff()` mas não consegui chegar no resultado que preciso.

Utilizando `in_array()`, os resultados que tem mais de uma DRADS aparecem duplicados.

Utilizando `array_diff()`, somente consigo exibir o `<select></select>` caso as DRADS sejam idênticas.

Não sei se consegui ser claro o suficiente, mas vou tentar deixar um exemplo do que preciso abaixo:

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
     $BD_01_DRADS = explode(",", $row['BD_01_DRADS']);
     $BD_02_DRADS = explode(",", $_SESSION['BD_02_DRADS']);

     $array1 = $BD_01_DRADS;
     $array2 = $BD_02_DRADS;
}
```

Então, preciso da seguinte condição: `SE TIVER $BD_01_DRADS EM $BD_02_DRADS, EXIBE UM <option>...</option> dentro do <select></select> com os respectivos dados deste registro`.

Pessoal, peço desculpas se não fui suficientemente claro. Mas estou à disposição para quaisquer esclarecimentos.

Toda e qualquer ajuda será bem vinda.

Obrigado a todos!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sera que o uso de array array_intersect resolve?

> Código

```
<?php
 $array1 = array(1,2,3);
 $array2 = array(1,2);
 $result = array_intersect ($array1, $array2);
?>
```

> Resultado

```
   array (
     0 => 1,
     1 => 2,
   )
```

**Vou deixar aqui uma indicação muito útil sobre teste de arrays on line.**

[array_intersect](http://array_intersect.onlinephpfunctions.com/)

[Funções disponíveis](http://onlinephpfunctions.com/categories/Arrays)

Comment: Amigão, obrigado pelo feedback! Infelizmente devido aos problemas rotineiros, não consegui tempo para avançar no projeto. Estarei testando o uso de array_intersect e posto os resultados na sequência.

Comment: Apliquei o array_intersect no projeto e funcionou perfeitamente para o que eu precisava! Obrigado pela força!